# file permission magento2 app/etc

Tags: permissions, installation, magento2

Hi I am trying to install magento2 on a vps centos

I followed the instructions about file permission in magento documentation 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html
I got the same erorr while installing :
/var/www/html/magento2/app/etc"  Not writable, change the permissions.

Do I need to restart apache after I change some permissions.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the setup wizard, it will ask you for permission to write to the app/etc/env.php

I would advise you to use the bin/magento cli tool to setup the app:

> php bin/magento setup:install

But it is fine to temporary allowing the web server to write to your env.php, after the UI wizard finished you can change it back to the correct file permission.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to clear cache.

- php bin/magento cache:flush
  or you can switch to the developer mode
- php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Answer (score 0):

Use below commands to set permissions and then restart apache:

```
sudo  usermod -g wwwrun <yourusername>
cd /var/www/html/magento2 && sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; && sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \; && sudo chown -R apache:apache . && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 0):

You need run this code:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/magento2/
chmod -R a+w /var/www/html/magento2/
```

Note: Magento2 is folder where you was install magento